# Is it really necessary to add .ConfigureAwait call when calling an awaitable method?

Tags: async-await, asp.net-mvc-5.2, configureawait

I am developing an application using Visual Studio 2019 with code validation.

Some code validation hints are important, however, I am getting a lot of hints in my awaitable method calls, such as

`var appUser = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());`

In this case, system is suggesting me to put

`var appUser = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()).ConfigureAwait(true);`

or

`var appUser = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Is it really necessary to dirty the code in such a way?

This is an MVC5 ASP.NET application.

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it really necessary to dirty the code in such a way?

If you [do not block](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), then you do not need `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

In the general case, [`ConfigureAwait(false)` is recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) because most code doesn't *know* whether its callers will block or not. But if this code is part of your application (i.e., not a library), and you're confident your application doesn't block on asynchronous code, then you're fine skipping the `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Stephen Toub recently published a [ConfigureAwait FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/).